# Adding javascript tracking to all Docusaurus pages

Tags: javascript, event-tracking, docusaurus

I'm looking to add this tracking javascript to all my pages and not quite sure how to accomplish it.

```
<head>
  <script src="//tagdelivery.website.com/utag.sync.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  ...
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Tealium Universal Tag -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(a,b,c,d) {
        a='//tagdelivery.website.com/utag.js ';
        b=document;c='script';d=b.createElement(c);d.src=a;
        d.type='text/java'+c;d.async=true;
        a=b.getElementsByTagName(c)[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(d,a)})();
  </script>

  ...
</body>
```

For the <head> section I believe I can just add the src to the 'scripts' section in my docusaurus.config.js, but I haven't found a way to add the function code to the body. Is this possible?

Directions from Tealium:
Implement – Tealium Tag Management System (TMS)
Description: The tag management system can be installed in two steps. Copy the first script below and paste it as high up in the  as possible for each page.  Then copy the second script below and paste it immediately after the opening  tag on each page. Typically, if master pages are used, this will be placed on the master page, so all pages inherit it.

Comment: The function adds a `<script>` tag. If you can actually add the `<script>` directly, you don't need the function.

Comment: The Tealium directions say I need to add both of them:2. Implement – Tealium Tag Management System (TMS)
Description: The tag management system can be installed in two steps. Copy the first script below and paste it as high up in the <head> as possible for each page.  Then copy the second script below and paste it immediately after the opening <body> tag on each page. Typically, if master pages are used, this will be placed on the master page, so all pages inherit it.

Comment: Well there are two different script URLs, either or both can be done as plain `<script>` tags or via that JavaScript. I have no idea why they would say that, but the net effect is exactly the same: a `<script>` tag imports a script and the script runs.